# What is the term for a person who doesn't waste time?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, epithet-requests

What is an English word/expression/idiom for a "person who doesn't waste time"?

Especially a person who doesn't look for excuses when she/he should be doing something productive e.g. *working*, *cleaning*, *cooking*

Comment: Could you provide us with some more context? If you're talking about work-related time management I would say that someone is *well-organised* or *productive*.

Comment: Also some who means business doesn't waste time.

Comment: More context, please!

Comment: Efficient.  Or "time-efficient", if you prefer.

Comment: Imaginary person

Comment: A person from myth, that managers are brainwashed into thinking exist when they are promoted to said manager position. (check the official secret managers handbook it's there).

Comment: are we asking for an antonym for *procrastinator* ?

Comment: I was gonna go with "non-crastinator".

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A **no-nonsense** person just gets it done.

Comment: This answer is a case in point. Kudos.

Comment: Looks like this is what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: *No-nonsense* really is more about being strict and unwavering, not so much that you don't waste time.

Comment: @insaner Indulging in nonsense is a waste of time.

Answer (score 31):

**industrious** could work

From Merriam Webster:

> constantly, regularly, or habitually active or occupied : diligent 
>   e.g. an industrious worker

Answer (score 16):

This person is *diligent*.

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/diligent):

> Having or showing care and conscientiousness in one’s work or duties.

Answer (score 15):

You may like

**busy bee**

Noun    1.  *busy bee* - an alert and energetic person

synonyms: eager beaver, ...
doer, actor, worker

a person who acts and gets things done ... a zealously energetic person (especially a salesman)

[Based on WordNet 3.0, Farlex clipart collection. © 2003-2012 Princeton University, Farlex Inc.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/busy+bee)

Another informal term is a **grafter**.

Comment: So funny...  As childish as it sounds, sometimes "busy bee" is the best expression. (I still catch myself using it, from time to time.)

Comment: Except that, to many, "busy bee" has a connotation of wasted motion.

Answer (score 8):

"To be **all business** or **strictly business**".

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/strictly+business

> strictly business
>
> 2. a person who is very businesslike and does not waste time with nonbusiness matters

If you want a single (albeit compound) word, you can say **businesslike**:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/businesslike

> businesslike
>
> 1. conforming to, attending to, or characteristic of business.
> 2. efficient, practical, or realistic.

However, personally, I find "businesslike" on its own a little weak, so if you want to suggest great focus, you might want to say **very businesslike** or **totally businesslike**.

**Highly focussed** is another phrase to consider.

**Purposeful** and **pragmatic** are also good words, but they have a slightly wider scope of meaning.

Answer (score 6):

Without context, it's difficult to understand what you mean by "waste time".  It's too broad and may refer to: leisure time and entertainment, commuting, stopping to work and chat for a few minutes, watch soap operas and sitcoms, wait for someone, wait in line, etc.

If it's about work, **a workaholic** is a person who compulsively works for long hours and finds no time for leisure.

> - workaholic" - (noun) a person who chooses to work a lot : a person who is always working, thinking about work. - My brother is a real workaholic who almost never takes time off. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/workaholic)

Answer (score 4):

**Efficient** is another one. From [Google](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8&q=efficient%20definition&oq=efficient%20defin&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3753j0j1):

> - Achieving maximum productivity with minimum wasted effort or expense.
> - Working in a well-organized and competent way.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. A real **[go getter](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/go-getter?q=go%20getter)** - An aggressively enterprising person
> 2. **[On the ball](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/on-the-ball?q=On%20the%20ball)** - Indicating competence, alertness, or intelligence
>
> From the Oxford Dictionary

Comment: Citation in the future please.

Comment: go-getter was my first thought.

Answer (score 2):

I like EleventhDoctor's suggestion of "diligent", but if you want another alternative, consider "**on task**", also sometimes spelled with a hyphen, "**on-task**".

"On task" is defined by [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/on+task) as "concentrating or focusing on what is to be done".

Answer (score 2):

> **[assiduous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/assiduous)** - adjective: showing great care and perseverance.
>
> From Oxford Dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

First thought was:

[***Gumptious***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gumptious)

The adjective form of **gumption**:

> Noun, Informal.
>
> *initiative*; aggressiveness; *resourcefulness*

(Oxford English Dictionary)

It's similar to industrious (see answer from Sky). It's not my favourite sounding word though ...

Comment: Was your first thought, "gumption?"  In any event, you've misspelled it. (And I can't do a 1-character edit) +1, though.

Comment: @stevesliva, gumption yes, however I went with the adjective version - as in a person with gumption is gumptious ... I've updated the answer to reflect this. It's very odd, I thought I copied and pasted the word, hence not checking. It's interesting to see that as it is my browser spell check is underlining it, however if I search for the word it turns up in the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody who uses all the available hours of the day, particularly to slave away on some task or project, is **burning the candle at both ends**.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/burn+the+candle+at+both+ends

This refers more to the duration than efficiency or intensity of the effort. But they are **making the most of** their time on earth (another idiom you might consider).

Answer (score 1):

**Focused**, **concentrated**, all refer to not deviating from the task or wasting time. You could even use **fixated** in proper context.

Answer (score 0):

A "**doer**" is one who does rather than thinks about doing

> [**Doer**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/doer) - a person characterized by action, as distinguished from
>   one given to contemplation.

Answer (score 0):

### Relentless

The connotations of relentless are conventionally [negative](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/relentless), but sometimes the word is used in a positive way.

> When you're [relentless](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/relentless) about something, you mean business. You're not stopping until you get what you want, and you're not taking "no" for an answer.